# How to edit or update a file for all commits and branches in git, using git filter-branch?

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I am trying to update the Repository URL in the package.json file in all of my branch and commits on my repo. There are multiple wayS to approach as always, I have tried to use git filter-branch delete the file in all commits and add new file back.

This is how I delete my file: 
`git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch package.json' HEAD` 
And now, I am trying to add a new package.json file with new git url.

Is there a better way to do this? I just want to update my git url in packagae.json since my old url content sensitive information of my company.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [BFG Repo-Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/)

It has `bfg --delete-files` or `bfg --replace-text`  which would allow you to remove a file (or replace some text within that file)

See more at "[Removing sensitive data from a repository](https://help.github.com/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository/)".